# I can't find the header in an ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I started supporting a simple blog website built on ASP.Net 4.6.1 MVC.  I'm brand new to MVC and have only worked on SPAs up till now.  My problem is, I can't find the header.  Normally, if I don't know the app I'll search for some unique text from the area I need.  This isn't working in this case, no results came up.

1. There is a background image in the header but there is no .jpg file in the repo and no link to an online image.
2. Everything I've read so far says the header should be a partial view but there is no _header.cshtml
3. The _Layout.cshtml doesn't reference the header.  In the body is @renderbody() and when I view source file in the browser, I see nav and header tags inside the body tag.

Here are some items I thought might help:

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Congress Sucks!</title>
    @*Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

@Html.Partial("_Menu")

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
@Html.Partial("_footer")
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The folder layout

[image]

The header with the inspector open
[image]

Comment: I'd assume it's in the "_Menu" partial view since it's above the body content, the navigation (navigation menu) is inside the `<header>` and the hero area with the background is in the `<header>` as well.

Comment: That would make perfect sense, except I can't find that view either.  <ugh>

Answer (score 1):

It was the "Show all files" setting in VS Solution Explorer.  That's embarrassing!